# Install libwidevinecdm0 on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, repository

I want to install `libwidevinecdm0` on Ubuntu 22.10.
for that I need to add RaspberryOS Bullseye repository.
Is there a way to hold everything **but** `libwidevinecdm0`?

THere is instructions in https://www.blackmoreops.com/2021/09/16/add-raspberry-pi-repository-in-ubuntu/ but I must hold everything else

Comment: Historically, mixing Ubuntu and Debian sources creates a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian), and that approach is considered unwise. We don't provide support for FrankenDebian systems. That you must "*hold everything else*" confirms that your chosen path seems unwise. This resembles an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) -- what are you trying to accomplish that has led you to believe that installing libwidevinecdm0 on Ubuntu 22.10 is a great solution?

Comment: @user535733 I want to use it for playing Netflix and Spotify on one hand and enjoy the more up to date kernel and the prettier gnome graphical interface...

Comment: Why do you want to install Raspberry Pi repository? Which software are you trying to install?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I'm trying to play Netflix on my Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu 22.10 64 bit, recently (Google?) released `libwidevinecdm0` for RaspberryOS 64 bit, there was already a version for 32 bit). the problem is that `libwidevinecdm0` can't be found on Canonical repositories so I need to add Debian's repository. but it's packages take control or precedence over the Ubuntu's repositories so in one hand, I don't want to install `libwidevinecdm0` and remove the repository so `libwidevinecdm0` won't get updates, on the other hand, I don't want to install anything else from Bullseye.

Comment: Just download the deb package and install it manually, instead of adding the whole repository

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi if I’ll do that, it won’t be managed and updated automatically with `apt`… I wanted it to be managed…

Comment: Debian/Raspbian/Ubuntu does not update most of its packages (except web browsers/kernels) during the lifetime of a particular release anyway.